# Vscode showInformationMessage message disappears, is there a timer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am faced with auto dismissing of my messages. For example I call   `vscode.window.showInformationMessage` and after a few seconds this message disappears. I can't find any info about options to control this, like with a timer, and `setStatusBarMessage` doesn't display my message. Please help me, guys.

Answer (score 0):

if user input is necessary,try to use modal like this

```
vscode.window.showInformationMessage('test',{modal: true},'yes','no');
```